# insert incremental values in an insert ... select statement mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a number of rows in a table, reverse the values in one column and reinsert them into the table.  Here is an example of what I am doing, say I have the following data:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| ORDER |   X    |   Y   |
+-------+--------+-------+
|  0    |   12   |   5   |
|  1    |   16   |   3   |
|  2    |   19   |   2   |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

I want to select it and reinsert it into the same table with the ORDER reversed as so:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| PORDER |   X    |   Y   |
+--------+--------+-------+
|  2     |   12   |   5   |
|  1     |   16   |   3   |
|  0     |   19   |   2   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

I am able to duplicate the rows and reinsert them, no problem using an insert ...  select like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (porder, x, y) SELECT porder, x, y FROM myTable
```

but I have had no success reversing the order.  I have tried

```
INSERT INTO myTable (porder, x, y) SELECT (SELECT porder FROM myTable ORDER BY porder DESC), x, y FROM myTable but that throws an error
```

It would be fine to simply ignore the porder column and insert new values from 0 to the highest number in the sequence (2 in my above example) but I don't know how to add sequential numbers in a multiple-row insert statement in mysql.

I know how to do this with php but I was thinking there must be a more elegant solution in just SQL

Comment: What's the error message? Have you thought about using a temporary table? `CREATE TABLE TMP ...`. `INSERT INTO TMP SELECT ... myTable`. `DROP TABLE myTable`. `RENAME TABLE TMP TO myTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    INSERT INTO myTable(`porder`, x, y) SELECT (SELECT MAX(`porder`) FROM myTable) - `porder`, x, y FROM myTable
```

Comment: unfortunately the SELECT MAX causes it to only select 1 row from each set of points.  Oddly it also returned that row with the porder of 0, I would have expected it to be 2 (porder max of 2 - porder of 0 = 2) but I will play some more with this as it seems to have promise

Comment: so I gave your answer and @Basti's both an up vote because combining the 2 got me on the right track.  I had to had a second query to pull the max porder and assign it to a variable so not quite as clean as I would have liked but it works.  If someone has a more elegant solution I would appreciate seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the max-value of `order`, you can simply do (assuming `max(order) = 2`)

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `PORDER` = 2 - `PORDER`
```

Example:

```
   +--------+------------+
   | PORDER | 2 - PORDER |
   +--------+------------+
   |  0     |  2-0 = 2   |
   |  1     |  2-1 = 1   |
   |  2     |  2-2 = 0   |
   +--------+------------+
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know the max, it changes from case to case, but thank you.

Comment: So I used a separate query to get the max value and then used @nauphal's solution above.  So thank you for the idea!